# loading enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql into mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to load the wikipedia category-links table into the MySql database.
I used the following command in the terminal:

```
mysql -u root -proot categorylinks < enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql
```

The file is 11.6 GB in size and running since 3 days.
Is there any better way to load it faster or some settings i need to set to make it run faster ???

Comment: Check your database status and if it's running and table size getting bigger, you may want to give it more time. It might be close. If it really bothers you,or you will run similar file again, check the file contents and remove keys ,constrains on large tables before run it again.

Comment: This question is in its current status too broad. It could be anything. It sounds like you are running MySQL with its default configuration. Then it's no wonder it takes forever. MySQL is very careful to not use too much memory. Therefore your installation is running with handbrakes on.

Comment: @fancyPants  then please tell how to run the installation without handbrakes on

Answer (score 5):

**1) Separate the SQL dump file to two parts: creation and data**

1. `grep  -n "Dumping data" enwiki-latest-redirect.sql`

This will return the line number separating the creation and data of the table parts of the file. Let it be 46.

2. `tail  -n +46 enwiki-latest-redirect.sql  > redirect -data.sql`

The number we get in the last command is used as the input to `tail` to get the data part of the file.

3. `head -46 enwiki-latest-redirect.sql  > redirect-creation.sql`

The number we get in the first command is used as the input to `head` to get the table creation part of the file.

**2) Remove indexes from the redirect-creation.sql**

The following is the original `CREATE TABLE` statement in the dump:

```
CREATE TABLE `redirect` ( 
 `rd_from` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 `rd_namespace` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 `rd_title` varbinary(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
 `rd_interwiki` varbinary(32) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `rd_fragment` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (`rd_from`),   
  KEY `rd_ns_title` (`rd_namespace`,`rd_title`,`rd_from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary;
```

The following is the desired version after removing the indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE `redirect` ( 
 `rd_from` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 `rd_namespace` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 `rd_title` varbinary(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
 `rd_interwiki` varbinary(32) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `rd_fragment` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary;
```

Edit the page-creation.sql to remove indexes as shown above.

**3) Load the created files**

```
mysql -u root -p wikipedia < redirect-creation.sql
mysql -u root -p wikipedia < redirect-data.sql
```

**4) Create indexes on fields you want after loading the data**

```
create index idx_redirect_rd_from on redirect(rd_from)
```

I am able to load the categorylinks table in under an hour on my Macbook Pro by following the steps above.

Comment: This works well for me. It took roughly 2-4 hours on my laptop to load `categorylinks`.

Comment: Tested as of this month, the dumps now contain a statement `/*!40000 ALTER TABLE \`category\` DISABLE KEYS */;` followed by `INSERT`s followed by `/*!40000 ALTER TABLE \`category\`` ENABLE KEYS */;` which I believe should make the split described in this answer unnecessary. It is still slow and cumbersome though! This CSV dumper is also of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63035431/how-do-i-download-and-work-with-wikipedia-data-dumps/77365126#77365126