# Extracting parent category ID from wiki API using article ID?

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia

Using an [external tool](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor) to parse Wikipedia articles from the dump files(e.g.enwiki-20200401-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2)
 Now, given the parsed object I have for each article I have it's wiki ID, and the Categories as strings
E.g.

```
{'Title':'The Dark Knight (film)',
'id':4276475,
'Categories':['2008 films',English-language films,'2000s action thriller films',...,]
}
```

Unfortunately, these categories are too fine-grained, and I'm trying to get (e.g here action thriller films), thus, trying to find the parent categories of each category in the articles list.
Extracting the category was relatively straight-forward:

```
import wptools
page = wptools.page('The Dark Knight (film)')
categories_and_more = page.get_more()
one_category = wptools.page(categories_and_more.data['categories'][0])
```

But extracting all the categories that see this category as a sub-category was not straight-forward.

Comment: Not sure what's exposed by wptools, but the API can take a `pageid` parameter instead of `title`. But also, [deepcat search](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#Deepcategory) might be an easier (if more limited) approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately, as I tried to query for all the categories, The API blocked me for too many requests. I am now trying to extract it using the dump files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to do once you have `categorylinks.sql` inside your SQL server. You would just get the rows where `cl_from=article_id`, and the parent's title would be given by the column `cl_to`. You can search up the parent's id by getting another table, `page.sql`, and reverse searching up the id using `page_namespace=14 AND page_title=parent_title`.

Unfortunately, the dumps are pretty big and importing them can take pretty long. See here for how to speed the imports up: [loading enwiki-latest-categorylinks.sql into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30387731/6276743)