# wiki dump extract only articles about people,books,places

Tags: python, wikipedia

I want to create a NER (Name Entity Recognition) database from the Wikipedia dump. I need to extract the titles of articles by categories like: person, place, animal, company and etc.
How can I achieve this using python code? I already tried

- [wikipedia_ner](https://github.com/JonathanRaiman/wikipedia_ner) library but it's not working and gets empty result every time.
- [wiki_dump_parser](https://github.com/Grasia/wiki-scripts/tree/master/wiki_dump_parser) coverts XML dump to csv but the    only useful
  information is the page title
- [wikidump-infobox-extractor](https://github.com/EricWiener/wikidump-infobox-extractor).It only extracts the info box of articles that already have an infobox. there are few articles like this and categorizing it is very difficult.

Comment: You have to provide some code that you have tried so far, otherwise it is code writing request that is not supported way of solving issues on this website

Comment: It is more about, you write a code, it does not work as you expected, describe your issue with code attached, wait for help

Answer (score 0):

Working with categories is rather complex as of September 2020 based on wikipedia dump or [html dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934708/how-do-i-prepare-to-use-entire-wikipedia-for-natural-language-processing).

Your best bet will be to hit wikidata or dbpedia with some [sparql] queries.

Try for instance that query that retrieve all "subject" that have a "type" as "Person"

```
select distinct ?subject where {
  ?subject <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>
} LIMIT 100
```

[results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3Fsubject+where+%7B%3Fsubject+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPerson%3E%7D+LIMIT+100%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)